# Changing HTML attributes

Tags: html, powershell, scripting, web-scraping

A website has a form that has its textboxes "disabled" by default thus forcing you to enter information starting with the first box then working your way down the list.

This does not allow my PowerShell script to automatically put in information.

I found that if I manually set the disable attribute to `""` (or null) it will unlock the different textboxes and then will allow information to be entered.

How can I tell PowerShell to "delete" the `disabled` attribute? Current code does not work.

[image: Powershell Code]

[image: HTML Code]

Comment: Please do not post code as pictures. Copy/paste the text and format it with the `{}` button above the edit box.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` isn't enumerable, so your `foreach` loop is looking for a `disabled` attribute in the `<div>` element itself and can't find it. You need to iterate over the element's children to get to the element you want to modify. It's also not the value of the element you want to look at, but the value of one of the element's attributes.

```
foreach ($element in $t.children) {
  if ($element.disabled -eq 'disabled') { $element.disabled = '' }
}
```